# Universal Windows Platform ( UWP ) Application with Videos - App Packaging for distribution

Tags: video, win-universal-app, packaging

UWP application plays videos from a specific folder as you navigate through different screens.

if i've to package this UWP application and share it on Windows Store , should i've to place all the videos inside the application i.e, Place all videos inside **Assets** folder and then create a package ( which i don't want to do ). Going with this approach increases the size of the app to GBs , because of number of videos.

Can anybody here suggest alternative approaches for packaging and distributing of this App ?

Thanks much.

Comment: If you want the videos to be included with the application, they'll need to be part of the package. If downloading them later isn't an option, it's not clear what other option you might be looking for.

Comment: Yes i agree and am aware of that is one of the options. But in my app there number of videos , and i can package them it'll simply bump up the application size. Instead i was thinking like , if i just store some relative path of the videos by placing them outside the application , then in that case app and videos become loosely coupled. I can even replace the videos as well. So was checking if any body has such sort of experience  , if so would like to listen to their experiences.

Comment: Your comment on an answer below stays that the videos have to be part of the app download.

Comment: I understand. what i meant there was , if we have installer kind of thing , we can package App and videos combined. when we install this on system they both gets installed on the machine. if at all user wants to change those videos and replaced with another set of videos , he can simply do on his machine by replacing another video with same file names. Hope this is clear now. if not , please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrated whole problem and solution in detail @ <http://www.madugulavenkataramana.com/2016/09/11/uwp-app-distribution-with-lots-of-data/>

Answer (score 0):

If you have couple of video files, sure best way is to allow user to download them later. Just add Videos Library capability and download videos to this folder with [backgroundTransfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207242)

Comment: There is no downloading of videos. it has to go along with the application.

Answer (score 0):

After good amount of research on this topic , found out the answer for the problem.

- UWP App will not have videos inside it.( if we place all videos inside the App Package , the UWP App size exceeds > 25GB which is a limitation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements - **Check for Package format requirements** )
- UWP App is separated from the videos by depending on JSON files  which contains information about videos , images etc., .
- When the App starts it looks for it's Local directory for JSON files.
  It'll not find these as App running for the first time.
- Prompts user to insert a USB drive which has JSON and Video files
  directory. Upon USB drive insertion , UWP App copies files from USB
  drive to Local Directory.
- Once all the files copied successfully , App Starts and shows the videos.
- This idea of downloading videos from USB can be further extended to Internet as well , such that by prompting user to download videos from a specific URL location.

Hope this information helps.